# Python - Why does timedelta64 values appear as 0 in excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one of the column as `timedelta64` dtype. The values appear to be fine in IDE but when I export the dataframe to excel using `ExcelWriter` and `to_excel()`, the values in the Excel are all 0. *(It's actually not 0 but a very small floating points.)*

Comment: Did you try changing the format of column display in Excel?

Comment: That will fix the problem but i wish to fix it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you export the values to an .xls file do you get the same issue? XLS is a binary file format, not a collection of XML files. This should allow you to check whether this is a file format issue or not.

Comment: This should be comment cont an answer

Comment: I can't add a comment until I have 50 reputation.